# boost-iostreams 1.59 sparc-solaris crosscompilation fails

Tags: linux, boost, cross-compiling, solaris, sparc

boost sources: sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.59.0/boost_1_59_0.tar.gz

host machine x64-linux, ubuntu 20

crosscompiler `sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++ (GCC) 4.9.3`

steps, based on this tutorial https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=iostreams

# replace in file project-config.jam the line "using gcc ;" with the line "using gcc : sparc : /opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++ ; "
sed -i 's,using gcc ;,using gcc : sparc : /opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++ ;,' project-config.jam 

./b2 toolset=gcc-sparc target-os=solaris
```

The result

```
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : yes

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - symlinks supported       : yes
    - zlib                     : yes
    - zlib                     : yes

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - coroutine2               : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 768 targets...
...updating 28 targets...
common.mkdir stage
common.mkdir stage/lib
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o
/tmp/cc794ayD.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1152: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1152: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1896: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1896: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1927: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:1927: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:4526: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:4526: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:4558: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:4558: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5235: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5235: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5274: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5274: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5444: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5444: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5483: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5483: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5653: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5653: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5692: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5692: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5862: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5862: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5901: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:5901: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:6069: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:6069: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:6101: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc794ayD.s:6101: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)

    "/opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -mcpu=v7 -pthreads -fPIC -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o" "libs/iostreams/src/file_descriptor.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:1648: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:1648: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:2758: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:2758: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:2789: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:2789: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:4852: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:4852: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:4884: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:4884: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:5039: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:5039: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:5071: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccWae5Mg.s:5071: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)

    "/opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -mcpu=v7 -pthreads -fPIC -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o" "libs/iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/bzip2.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/gzip.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/zlib.o
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.59.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>file_descriptor.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.59.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.59.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.59.0...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1057: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1057: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1301: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1301: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1332: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:1332: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:2108: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:2108: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:2145: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:2145: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6555: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6555: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6592: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6592: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6739: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6739: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6884: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:6884: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7349: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7349: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7493: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7493: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7958: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:7958: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8026: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8026: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8206: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8206: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8277: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8277: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8455: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8455: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8492: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8492: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8627: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8627: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8695: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8695: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8875: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8875: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8943: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:8943: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9123: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9123: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9194: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9194: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9374: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9374: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9445: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9445: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9625: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9625: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9758: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:9758: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10187: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10187: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10327: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10327: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10756: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10756: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10897: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:10897: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:11326: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:11326: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:11460: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/cc75PcHu.s:11460: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)

    "/opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -mcpu=v7 -pthreads -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o" "libs/iostreams/src/file_descriptor.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1692: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1692: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1847: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1847: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1878: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:1878: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:4451: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:4451: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:4518: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:4518: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7007: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7007: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7038: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7038: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7397: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7397: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7428: Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g3],%g2,%g1".
/tmp/ccfD3w4Y.s:7428: (Requires v9|v9a|v9b|v9c|v9d|v9e|v9v|v9m|m8; requested architecture is v8.)

    "/opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -mcpu=v7 -pthreads -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o" "libs/iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/mapped_file.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/bzip2.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/gzip.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/zlib.o
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>file_descriptor.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>file_descriptor.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.a...
...failed updating 4 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
...updated 18 targets...
```

It seems that these errors (`Error: Architecture mismatch on "cas [%g4],%g3,%g1".`) occur because sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++ compiles with the `-mcpu=v7` flag.

If I run sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++ without `-mcpu=v7`, for example:

`"/opt/crosssolaris/bin/sparc-sun-solaris2.10-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pthreads -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_IOST REAMS_USE_DEPRECATED -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-sparc/release/link-static/target-os-solaris/threading-multi/file_descriptor.o" "libs/iostreams/src/file_descriptor.cpp"`

, compilation is successful

Is there a way to exclude `-mcpu=v7` flag from compilation? Or some other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you're building a 32-bit library?  A SPARC v7 was *old* 25 years ago.  Try building a 64-bit library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the GCC SPARC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/SPARC-Options.html):

> These ‘-m’ options are supported in addition to the above **on SPARC-V9 processors in 64-bit environments**:
>
> -m32
>
> -m64
>
> Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit environment sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits. The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits.
>
> -mcmodel=which
>
> . . .

`-m32` implies a 32-bit build **on a 64-bit SPARC v9 CPU**.

Which means using the `-m32` option will cause GCC to emit `cas` instructions and likely others that exist in the SPARCv9 and later instruction sets, but that don't exist in the SPARC v7 instruction set.

See https://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2015/08/28211.php for a similar situation.

The fix there was to pass `instruction-set=v9` on the command line.